# Multiple shared lists of the same Bean Redbean

Tags: php, javabeans, shared, redbean

If I have a 'product' bean, and an 'upload' bean and I have two properties:

```
$product->sharedImageList;
$product->sharedManualList;
$product->sharedVideoList; // just here for another property 
                           //relating to another bean elsewhere
```

They both are using the 'upload' bean. But I cannot alias them. Can I not use the same bean for two shared lists? I know the shared-bean-list needs to be the same name as the bean, but fetchAs works below...

```
$teacher = $c->fetchAs( 'person' )->teacher;
```

I have tried

```
$product->fetchAs('upload')->sharedImageList
//getting desperate now
$product->via('upload')->sharedImageList
$product->alias('upload')->sharedImageList
```

## **You can use this to test my issue**

```
<?php
include_once 'rb.php';

error_reporting( E_ALL );
R::addDatabase( "my_site", "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_db", "root", "", false );
R::selectDatabase( 'my_site' );

\R::nuke();

$images  = [
    ["id" => 1,'name'=>"image"],
    ["id" => 2,'name'=>"test image2"],
];
$manuals = [
    ["id" => 1,'name'=>"test1"],
    ["id" => 2,'name'=>"test manual2"],
];

$product = R::findOneOrDispense( 'product', ' id=? ', [1] );

$product->sharedImageList  = []; //empty / create new shared image list
$product->sharedManualList = []; //empty / create new shared manual list
$product->name             = "im a product"; // give product a name for giggles

foreach ($images as $object) {
    $upload                     = R::findOneOrDispense( 'upload', " id = ? ", [$object['id']] );
    $upload->name               = $object['name'];
    $product->sharedImageList[] = $upload;
}

foreach ($manuals as $object) {
    $upload                      = R::findOneOrDispense( 'upload', " id = ? ", [$object['id']] );
    $upload->name                = $object['name'];
    $product->sharedManualList[] = $upload;
}

$product = R::load( 'product', R::store( $product ) );

echo '<pre>';
echo "\n\n<b>// this should return 2 beans of images that were uploaded</b>\n";
echo json_encode( $product->sharedImageList, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );


echo "\n\n<b>// this should return 2 beans of manuals that were uploaded</b>\n";
echo json_encode(  $product->sharedManualList, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );


echo "\n\n<b>// this is the only way i can access the shared lists, which is the name of the (upload) bean</b>\n";
echo json_encode( $product->sharedUploadList, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
echo "\n\n\n";
echo json_encode($product,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: just thoughts. I am confused by this code. Whenever I see a method 'dispense' in a 'redbeanphp' class then 1) I assume it is a `fused model` 2) I assume that 'redbeanphp' executes it when using `\R::dispense('bean');`. To debug this I would: create the bean separately then add it to the shared  lists checking each list in turn. I can then check what is happening at each step.

Comment: Would you setup a complete code, minimal example, that I can load and run?

Comment: I just appended some code for you

Comment: I edited it a bit to show feedback

Comment: You can set debug on to see what SQL is bring generated and used by redbeanphp. Also check the database tables at each step. That will help you to see what is actually happening,

Comment: Can you show 1) The input data you are using. 2) The source beans in the database. 3) what each 'product' bean is supposed to contain / link to.  3) exactly what results you expect to see for each product fetched? I can set it up but I need to see what you provide and what you expect as results.

Comment: All the code you need is in the  code block at the bottom of my post... copy>paste> run

Answer (score 0):

**[redbean](/questions/tagged/redbean) does not support `many to many` aliased relations** between a couple of beans !! (let's say `bean1` and `bean2`)

The workaround is to use an ad-hoc bean (let's say `bean_m2m` representing the "m2m-relation" and a couple of one-to many and many-to-one relations like this.

`bean1` - (one2manyRelation) - `bean_m2m` - (many2oneRelation) - `bean2`

To ease the queries, you may use (`aggr` functions)[https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/other_relations#aggr]

Comment: No. it's support since 5.x version .
https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/many_to_many